# python re.sub using() replace string within a line

Tags: python, regex

Trying to do something so simple: 
I have a line from a text file and I know the exact format. There are six integers in a row separated by spaces.

For example:

```
line = '78 170 180 1 2 3'
```

What I want to do is replace the fourth number with another number. This replacement is passed as a variable (i.e., not known and not hard-coded in):

```
num_replace_str
```

So, I want a piece of code like:

```
newline = re.sub(r'\d+\s\d+\s\d+\s(\d+)\s\d+\s\d+\s',num_replace_str,line)
```

that would yield a result as follows:

```
print newline
78 170 180 50 2 3
```

I just want to replace the 4th number, which I have tried grouped (), with the string num_replace_str (in this example num_replace_str = '50'.

Comment: `There are seven integers in a row separated by spaces.` But there are only 6.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Just a typo - I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could just split the string, insert the new value and `' '.join` it back together.

```
split = line.split()
split[3] = str(50)
new_line = ' '.join(split)
```

Example:

```
>>> line = '78 170 180 1 2 3'
>>> split = line.split()
>>> split[3] = str(50)
>>> new_line = ' '.join(split)
>>> print new_line
78 170 180 50 2 3
```

Not that this doesn't preserve consecutive runs of whitespace . . . If that's a critical requirement, then regex might be a better bet.

Comment: Simple and it works. Thanks @mgilson. If anyone can show me how to do it using re.sub(), though, I'd still really appreciate it!

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: A legacy reason (not worth explaining). The point is that it is a variable passed through a function, so I can't just use '50' but have the variable for it num_replace_str. I updated the example nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use capture groups for the parts of the line that you want to *keep*, not the parts you want to replace. Then you copy them to the replacement string by using `\n` to copy the match for the `n`th group.

```
re.sub(r'^((?:\d+\s+){3})\d+', r'\1' + num_replace_str, line)
```

Comment: it displays `'h 2 3'`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
>>> import re
>>> line = '78 170 180 1 2 3'
>>> num_replace_str = str(50)
>>> newline = re.sub(r'\d+(?=\s\d+\s\d+$)',num_replace_str,line)
>>> print newline
78 170 180 50 2 3
```

Through external `regex` module,

```
>>> import regex
>>> newline = regex.sub(r'(?<=^\d+\s\d+\s\d+\s)\d+',num_replace_str,line)
>>> print newline
78 170 180 50 2 3
```

Comment: it finds 3rd from the end i.e., it assumes that there are six numbers.

Comment: we know how many numbers actually present (6). So third from the last and fourth from the first will point out the number which was in the fourth position.